# How to determine the version of a resolved Ivy dependency from Ant?

Tags: ant, ivy

I have an ivy file with the following dependency:

```
<dependency org="totimm" name="techcentral" rev="1.6.+" conf="sdk->sdk" transitive="false"/>
```

Is there any way to determine the revision that is resolved (for example 1.6.0, 1.6.1, etc) from the ant file which orders the ivy resolve?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should be able to use the [`artifactproperty`](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/use/artifactproperty.html) task for this, something like:

```
<ivy:artifactproperty
     name="module.[module].rev" value="[revision]"/>
```

will set one property, holding the revision number, for each artifact resolved.

Comment: Works perfectly, thanks! I think I was looking at an old version of the documentation when I was searching for this. :o